# Magento 2 - Remove Category Image on top of Category Page

Tags: magento2, category, image

I want to hide the large category image that shows on the category page. What phtml file and code do I need to edit?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Take a look these files:

**- The layout**

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml
```

**- Template**

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/category/image.phtml
```

You can remove the image  via layout in your custom theme. For example, in your custom theme:

**app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.image" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Can we add the same code inside theme default.xml?

Comment: @jafar I'm not sure about that. But, did you try?

Comment: Yes, i tried it, It is working.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the following path and add `<referenceBlock name="category.image" remove="true"/>`

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.image" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```